# Using rootSolve for non-linear system in matrix form

Tags: r

For a part of my thesis I have to write a programm, which solves this system of non-linear equations:

[Equations 1](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$$&space;%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;%5Csigma%5E2_%7B1,1%7D&space;&&space;%5Csigma_%7B12,1%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Csigma_%7B12,1%7D&space;&&space;%5Csigma%5E2_%7B2,1%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;=&space;BB'&space;=&space;%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;b%5E2_%7B11%7D+b%5E2_%7B12%7D&space;&&space;b_%7B11%7Db_%7B21%7D+b_%7B12%7Db_%7B22%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;b_%7B11%7Db_%7B21%7D+b_%7B12%7Db_%7B22%7D&space;&&space;b%5E2_%7B21%7D+b%5E2_%7B22%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;$$&space;%5C%5C&space;%5C%5C&space;and&space;%5C%5C&space;%5C%5C&space;$$%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;%5Csigma%5E2_%7B1,2%7D&space;&&space;%5Csigma_%7B12,2%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Csigma_%7B12,2%7D&space;&&space;%5Csigma%5E2_%7B2,2%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;=&space;B%5CLambda&space;B'&space;=&space;%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;%5Clambda_1b%5E2_%7B11%7D+%5Clambda_2b%5E2_%7B12%7D&space;&&space;%5Clambda_1b_%7B11%7Db_%7B21%7D+%5Clambda_2b_%7B12%7Db_%7B22%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Clambda_1b_%7B11%7Db_%7B21%7D+%5Clambda_2b_%7B12%7Db_%7B22%7D&space;&&space;%5Clambda_1b%5E2_%7B21%7D+%5Clambda_2b%5E2_%7B22%7D&space;%5C%5C[0.3em]&space;%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;$$)

where $\Lambda$ is an diagonal matrix with $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as diagonal entries. Thus, we get six equations with six unknown parameters:

[Equations 2](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$%5Csigma%5E2_%7B1,1%7D=&space;b%5E2_%7B11%7D+b%5E2_%7B12%7D$&space;%5C%5C&space;$%5Csigma%5E2_%7B12,1%7D=&space;b_%7B11%7Db_%7B21%7D+b_%7B12%7Db_%7B22%7D$&space;%5C%5C&space;$%5Csigma%5E2_%7B2,1%7D=&space;b%5E2_%7B21%7D+b%5E2_%7B22%7D$&space;%5C%5C&space;$%5Csigma%5E2_%7B1,2%7D=&space;%5Clambda_1b%5E2_%7B11%7D+%5Clambda_2b%5E2_%7B12%7D$&space;%5C%5C&space;$%5Csigma%5E2_%7B12,2%7D=&space;%5Clambda_1b_%7B11%7Db_%7B21%7D+%5Clambda_2b_%7B12%7Db_%7B22%7D$&space;%5C%5C&space;$%5Csigma%5E2_%7B2,2%7D=&space;%5Clambda_1b%5E2_%7B21%7D+%5Clambda_2b%5E2_%7B22%7D$)

I tried to use the package rootSolve and found its introduction document which provided me with some example but without much explanation of their steps. I have been trying to code this according to the examples but am now lost as to how I can model this.
Any tips or sources with more information about this package would be helpful!
Thanks in advance!

What I did so far:

i) Tried to solve the system in non-matrix form, I extended the 'B' matrix with another row and used this as lampda and lampda2, which are x5 and x6 in my code respectively! As an error I get that the matrix is singular, which should not be possible. The values choosen arbitrarily.

```
model <- function(x) {
  F1 <- x[1]^2+x[2]^2
  F2 <- x[1]*x[3]+x[2]*x[4]
  F3 <- x[3]^2+x[4]^2
  F4 <- x[5]*x[1]^2+x[6]*x[2]^2 
  F5 <- x[5]*x[1]*x[3]+x[6]*x[2]*x[4]
  F6 <- x[5]*x[3]^2+x[6]*x[4]^2
  F7 <- x[5] (edit: is this how you model free-variables?)
  F8 <- x[6]
  c(F1 = 3, F2 = 23, F3 = 21, F4=2, F5=1, F6=4, F7, F8)

  }
  multiroot(f = model, start = c(1, 1, 1, 2,2,2,3,3))
```

ii) Tried to model the matrix form, the error here is that the number of derivatives returned is not equal to the ones in the initial condition.

```
f3 <- function(x){
  X<-matrix(ncol=2,nrow=3)
  Y1<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)
  Y2<-matrix(c(6,5,4,9),nrow=2,ncol=2)

  X[1:2,]%*%t(X[1:2,])-Y1,
  X[1:2,]%*%(X[3,]*diag(2))%*%t(X[1:2,])-Y2,
  )
}
multiroot(f3, start<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2))
```